# How to simulate hair dynamics in slow-motion?

Tags: physics, hair

With cloth simulation, I can simply set the speed multiplier to between 0 and 1 to make the simulation goes slowly. What about hair dynamics? I couldn't find the same settings or anything that has the same function.

Comment: what you can always do is increase fps and in video editor use the speed control.

Comment: Thank you @Chris for the suggestion. I just tried that, but increasing the fps doesn't make the hair simulation move slowly.

Comment: that's why i wrote "...and in video editor use the speed control" -> with this you can make every video slower or quicker.

Answer (score 0):

How to make a image sequence/video animation slower/quicker:

1. File -> New -> Video editing

[image]

2. Shift-A -> Image Sequence

[image]

3. Shift-A -> Effect Strip -> Speed Conrol

[image]

[image]

4. Select your strip and drag the right white bar to the right to slow down your video.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just tried this, it doesn't make a smooth slow motion... You see, I want a slow motion without changing the fps. So what I do with objects are stretching the keyframe positions, then with the cloth simulation I can set the speed multiplier to lower. And now I wonder how to do the same to hair simulations...

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible. So i showed you a workaround.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks @Chris